# Experience manager installation

Tags: experience-manager

I was installing EXperience manager and followed all the steps given in guide:
1)Installing the Experience Manager Web service as a .NET Web application
2) Adding the Experience Manager Web site extension to a .NET Web site
After completeion of second step (XPM website extension), I am getting the[image] following error in my web application:

If I remove Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule" tag from web.config , it works fine.
Pls do let me know any further information is required.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like you have incorrect information in your Ambient Data Framework configuration files.

Have a look at cd_cartridge_conf.xml and cd_ambient_conf.xml in your Content Delivery web application's bin/config directory or in %TRIDION_HOME%/config

You probably still have the example configuration in there which does not work.

Comment: I got my this error resolved but having another one now.